# knocked several people down -- what does this mean? (context provided)

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Sams Teach Yourself TCP/IP in 24 Hours by Joe Casad (2012)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672335719)

Example:

> Configuring the router as a DHCP server was easy, at least for Maurice, because he
>   read the documentation carefully and wasn’t afraid to look for help on the Web. (He
>   did need to make sure the internal routers he installed on Day 2 were configured to
>   pass on the DHCP information.) The hard part was manually configuring each of
>   the 1,000 computers to access the DHCP server and receive an IP address dynamically. To configure the 1,000 computers in an 8-hour day, he had to configure 125 computers per hour, or a little more than 2 per minute. This would have been nearly
>   impossible for anyone but Maurice. **He knocked several people down**, but he finished in time for the 6:00 p.m. bus.

As simple and basic the idiom *to knock someone down* may sound, I don't think I really understand what exactly it means in this particular context.

Comment: To me (native British English speaker) it conveys nothing beyond its literal meaning, and appears as a wild _non sequitur_. Given the context, I can make a guess that it is meant to imply that he went for it wildly, ignoring everything else, but I've never encountered it in this sense. However I can think of another phrase which could be used in this sense, which is "He took no prisoners, and finished. .."

Comment: +1 for someone who posts the source, and includes the context with the sentence. If only every asker did the same!

Comment: OP may be interested in the subject matter of the book, so I don't want to impute any motives, but I would like to point out that how-to books about computer technology are carefully edited only rarely; a frequent goal of such books is to be first-to-market, and reading them is not a good way to develop English writing skills.

Comment: Actually, I think it is fairly literal, and sensible - Maurice had to manually configure each of the 1000 computers in one day; this implies that he had to run around really fast to get to each one, and probably was not too concerned about the people in his way if he had to get to a different computer every 30 seconds!

Comment: since the topic here is network configuration, it could mean that he inadvertently knocked some people's computers offline

Comment: What follows the sentence?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2H5uWRjFsGc

Comment: Sounds like Maurice was quite the amateur since all of that could have been done with a remotely executed script.

Comment: @corsiKa: Yup, that's the point.

Comment: @corsiKa generally doing stuff through a remotely executed script requires that you have a functional network and have remote access already set up.

Comment: Is the phrase "knock X down" an idiom?  I think it's just a verb here.  'Knock up' is surely an idiom but not 'knock down' right?  That would mean 'knock into', 'knock over'.  'knock out' is questionable.  'knock it off' and 'knock off' are surely idiomatic.  I have never really considered how often this word is used in common dialog.

Comment: @JimmyJames I agree, but don't forget "knock on wood" (superstition), "knock on" (sports), and "knockout" (women). Also, you can "knock X down a few pegs/notches" or "knock down a few drinks". Finally, "knock up" is used in some video games (like League of Legends) as jargon for a class of ability effects.

Comment: hm, I was in school with a Joe Casad, forty years ago!

Comment: @JimmyJames - 'Knock down' is certainly a UK idiom. Without a qualifier it would be 'by a car', otherwise it would have a qualifier... "Fred was knocked down on his way to work yesterday" == by a car, otherwise,  "Fred was knocked down by a [car/bus/rampaging bull/hurrying commuter etc]"

Comment: @Jeutnarg, does the "class of ability effects" mainly involve infecting someone else with your DNA, causing them to slowly bloat up before popping out another player?

Comment: @1006a - I had to carefully read back to your referenced comment before I spat my coffee at the screen laughing:) I'm afraid the US simply don't understand the UK's usage of 'knock up' which, as you so precisely pointed out, means only one thing here - making someone pregnant ;)

Comment: I don't think "knock down" is an idiom, exactly, just a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The author is simply making a joke; the image is of Maurice rushing from computer to computer, knocking people down (perhaps unintentionally) because he's moving impossibly fast and is on an impossibly tight schedule.

Since Maurice is a fictional character, and not at all intended to be realistic — what he's doing is clearly impossible — I think the phrase probably *is* intended literally; it's just a humorous vignette.

(I also disagree with the suggestions above that this passage is poorly-written or poorly-edited. I find it quite clear. The point of the hyperbole — the character moving so fast that he's knocking people down — is to emphasize that this is *not* a practical way to configure such a large number of machines.)

Answer (score 12):

It isn't an idiom per se, it is simply a comment that is not meant literally. Maurice was in a rush for the bus, as he spent too much time completing his other tasks. He probably didn't *actually* knock anybody down, but it conjures up a mental image of people being accidentally knocked in all directions as he runs through the crowd.

Edit: As @jwodder comments, on re-reading it can also be read as him knocking people down moving *between* computers to complete the job.

Comment: He need not have been in a rush for the bus, merely in a rush to travel between all of the computers in eight hours.

Comment: @jwodder That's very true. Good point.

Comment: Although this is probably what it is trying to imply, the phrase still seems out of place though. In one sentence it is talking about working hard on the DHCP configuration problem, then suddenly in the next sentence it is talking about knocking people down to get to the bus

Comment: @user13267 I don't see the problem.

Comment: At two computers per computer, he had to hurry people away from their computers in order to finish in time.  So he was likely gruff in his efforts to persuade people to allow him access to finish the task.

Comment: @xQbert I don't think it implies that. Knocking them _down_ implies them being standing, and thus not at computers.

Comment: I think this answer is _most likely_ what was meant by the phrase "knocked down", and even then it is ambiguous whether the people were knocked down _while_ Maurice was working or _after._ The main thing to take away from this question, I think, is, "Don't write like that."

Comment: I don't see it as an idiom for running for the bus; instead for running round the office... "knocked several people down, but he finished in time..." implies he knocked them down *before* he left work. [Agreed, it's a lousy construct, but to take it as written]